# How to pass id from while loop to controller [laravel]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel, so I'm searching for how to send a specific id to the controller in order to get data from another table ?

For example

```
while($shipment = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_customer_rule,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    //display some data ......

    // inside the loop i will have another query to get data from another table has //relation with shipment table

    $id = $shipment['id'];
    $customer = "SELECT * FROM [ccctadm].[customer] WHERE id = '$id' ";

    $get_customer_info = sqlsrv_query($conn, $customer);
    $get_customer_id = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_customer_info,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

    $customer_id = $get_customer_id['customerid'];
}
```

I can't write query in while loop in laravel, so how can I pass shipment id to the controller so I can get customer data related to the shipment

Answer (score 2):

Since you are new to Laravel, maybe you should learn the Laravel way first. Watch this video on how to work with Eloquent and perhaps every other video in that series. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/7

Once you get your head around that, you will be able to rewrite your query as

```
$shipments = Shipement::all();
foreach( $shipments as $shipment ) {
    $customer = $shipment->customer;
    $customer_id = $customer->id;
}
```

Even better when you get a bit further with laravel and be able to work with eager loading, you will just do

```
$shipments = Shipment::with('customer')->get();
```

And in your view

```
@foreach($shipments as $shipment)
    Customer ID is : {{ $shipment->customer->id }}
@endforeach
```

You have decided you to work with Laravel. Take advantage of it. It will make everything easier and speed up your development process.

If you want to stick to your raw SQL queries, you can use the query builder

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM [ccctadm].[customer] WHERE id = ?", [$id]);
```

And work with the result

Comment: I know all of these, I've watch 3 courses, but non of them include this situation to send id without  URL to the controller. I knew the only solution is to use joins to connect all of them together , but I though I might find and easier method. Thank you for your explanation